# PHP Location и скрипт

Tags: javascript, php

Это часть кода формы регистрации. Мой вопрос про Location. В моем случае нажатие на кнопку регистрации оставляет пользователя на той же странице, но проблема в том, что окно регистрации я открываю с помощью скрипта, так что оно автоматически закрывается после нажатия... А я хочу, чтобы после нажатия на кнопку, окно регистрации осталось открытым... как это организовать?

```
else {
        $password = md5($password);
        $connect->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`full_name`, `login`, `email`, `password`, `avatar`) VALUES ('$full_name', '$login', '$email', '$password', '$avatar')");
        $_SESSION['message'] = 'You are successfully registered!';
        header('Location: /');
    }
```

Comment: Что в вашем понимании означает термин "окно"?

Comment: Блок регистрации появляется только с помощью скрипта, а в начальной странице у него display: none; ...

Comment: @Ерванд С-ян Можно использовать `localstorage` или `session`. Уточните Ваш вопрос. У Вас через `js` проставляется полю `diplay: block`, Вы просто хотите сохранить отображение данного блока при location страницы из `php`?

Comment: используйте ajax для отправки данных формы на сервер. Тогда страница не будет перезагружаться

Comment: Да, Денис, именно этого хочу, ведь в начальной странице у блока дисплей нон, и при location, скрипт сам по себе, естественно не работает ...

Comment: либо ajax, либо пиши куда-то данные, что у тебя форма открыта, и проверяй в самом начале, но как по мне, костыли, ajax тру вей будет